# Every proper subgroup is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G\neq  1$ be a finite group. Suppose that every proper subgroup of $G$ is
Abelian. Then prove: $G$ contains a nontrivial Abelian normal subgroup.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: What do you want us to do with what you wrote? You want us to prove that?

Comment: Check this: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finite_non-abelian_and_every_proper_subgroup_is_abelian_implies_not_simple

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer. Thnx

Comment: This is Exercise 6, Section 1.3, from *The Theory of Finite Groups* by Kurzweil & Stellmacher.

Answer (score 0):

This is Exercise 6, Section 1.3, from *The Theory of Finite Groups* by Kurzweil & Stellmacher.

For those who would like a hint better than a solution [cf. the comment by @Scientifica above], suppose that $G$ is simple and nonabelian. Then

1. Show that the intersection of any two maximal (proper) subgroups is trivial.
2. Observe that if $M$ is maximal, $M^x$ is maximal too for any $x\in G\setminus M$.
3. Use Exercises 11 and 12 from Section 1.1.